# Detect AWS cron job non-execution and trigger alarms to send emails via SNS topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have developed a Lambda function to send personal emails and set up an **AWS cron job** to automate the process, **scheduling the emails to be sent quarterly on the first day of each quarter.**

Now, I would like to implement a mechanism that sends an email to the administrator if the AWS cron job fails to run. I mean that The cron job failed to execute.

I have attempted to use **AWS CloudWatch log metric filters and alarms**

[image]

I try to **create a metric to filter by log** (for example, if the AWS cron job works, there will be a log). I rely on that log to decide if the aws cron job is activated or not ( **if log count > 0 means it is activated**).

I've employed the "**Treat missing data as bad (breaching threshold)**" mechanism to trigger the alarm because when the cron job doesn't run, no new log is generated

However, I'm encountering an issue while setting up the **Period, Evaluation Periods, and Datapoints for the Alarm. Since the cron job runs only once in a quarter (approximately every 90 days), and the Metrics can't be monitored across more than a day.**

How can I monitor the data point over all 90 days to detect if the cron job hasn't been triggered?

Could someone please provide me with an idea or suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776437/cloudwatch-alarm-for-invocation-of-lambdas-with-scheduling-periods-1-day